# Leitura BD SQLite Android Studio (Kotlin)

Tags: kotlin

Seguinte pessoal, estou com um problema na hora de ler um dado do banco de dados, com o seguinte método:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém estou com esse pequeno problema na linha 68. Onde está falando que espera um valor do tipo `Tipo()` e eu estou passando uma `String`, só que quando eu coloco referenciando minha classe `Tipo()` dessa forma:

> t.tipo = result.getString(result.getColumnIndex(COL_TIPO)).Tipo

Ele não aceita.

Essa é minha classe tipo:

```
enum class Tipo {
    RECEITA
    {
        override fun toString(): String
        {
            return "RECEITA"
        }
    },
    DESPESA
    {
        override fun toString(): String
        {
            return "DESPESA"
        }
    }

}
```

Se alguém tiver alguma ideia, ou um método melhor pra leitura.

Essa é minha model Transacao na qual tenho meus atributos:

```
class Transacao(var valor: BigDecimal,
                var categoria: String = "Indefinida",
                var tipo: Tipo,
                var data: Calendar = Calendar.getInstance()) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver, apenas precisava declarar o `Tipo` após o igual e receber um `valueOf` do tipo string, ficando da seguinte forma:

```
t.tipo = Tipo.valueOf(result.getString(result.getColumnIndex(COL_TIPO)).toString())
```